# Change class instance variable from a module

Tags: ruby, module, ruby-on-rails-5, class-variables, activesupport-concern

I have several classes (Elves, Dwarves, Giants, etc.), and I would like to add "powers" to them via a powerable module that lets me add several fields/methods to a model (I am using Mongoid just for the sake of example) using a simple DSL `has_superpower(power_name)`

```
module Powerable::Elf
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include Powerable::Mongoid

  has_superpower(:super_hearing)
  has_superpower(:night_vision)
end

class Elf
  include Powerable::Elf
end
```

Each time I call the class method `has_superpower(power_name)`, it should register the `power_name` somewhere so I can later get the list of all added powers on a class (and reflect on those names to call other methods).

I don't know how to do that. I had a look at class instance variables or class variables but I'm not sure how to use them for this context

Consider the following boilerplate

```
module Powerable
  module Mongoid
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def use_power!(power_name, options = {})
      send(:"last_#{power_name}_used_at=", Time.now)
      ...
      # Log the power use to the :#{power_name}_uses array
      push(#{power_name}_uses, power: power_name, time: Time.now, **options)
    end

    class_methods do
      def has_superpower(power_name)
        field :"last_#{power_name}_used_at", type: DateTime
        field :"last_#{power_name}_count", type: Integer
        field :"#{power_name}_uses", type: Array
      end
    end
end
```

Now I would like to define a method that gives me all the uses of all superpowers. For this I would need to register the powers one has, so I can resolve the model fields I need to look at

```
# I am adding the following to the above module Powerable::Mongoid
module Powerable
  module Mongoid
    def power_uses(power_name = nil)
      if power_name.blank? # Retrieve all power uses)
        self.class.all_powers.flat_map do |power_name|#  I do not know how to code all_powers
          send(:"#{power_name}_uses")
        end
      else
        send(:"#{power_name}_uses")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The idea

```
elf = Elf.new
elf.use_power!(:night_vision, moon: :crescent)
elf.use_power!(:super_hearing, distance: 1.kilometer)
elf.power_uses # => [
 power: night_vision, time: xxx, moon: :crescent,
 power: super_hearing, time: xxx, distance: 1.kilometer
]
```

Comment: Why don't you put the "power uses" in an array?

Comment: Honestly, I'm completely lost at what you're trying to achieve here... `def use_power!`, `push(#{power}_uses`, `def has_superpower`, `module Elf`, `class Elf`, `def power_uses`, `self.class.all_powers`, `send(:"#{power}_uses")`, ... It looks like a complete jumble between multiple different implementations :S

Comment: @TomLord My original real problem is related to tracking email campaigns but for the sake of examples, I thought i'd be easier if I tried to feature an universe with elves, dwarves, etc.
The Idea is that I need to be able to handle some behavior in my classes that is registered using modules. I have a generic module to register a superpower and track its uses. In addition to this, I need to provide a different method that will aggregate all superpower uses

Comment: @Stefan you mean a `field(:power_uses)` that would keep track of evey power (regardless of its type ?) That's actually viable but I'd rather have this data sorted appropriately in my mongoid documents (for easier querying etc.) and avoid duplication within the same document.